# Same Method for Client and Server slightly different behavior

Tags: java

Most of my classes have different behavior if they are client or server side. (client: gui, server: connection stuff) but they also have some common behavior. I want to know what's the best way to do this.

Example content of a class:

```
public class Example{
    private void commonMethod(){
        //common code
    }

    public void clientMethod(){
        commonMethod()
        //Client code
    }

    public void serverMethod(){
        commonMethod()
        //Server code
    }

}
```

What i want:

- 1 method with some way to specify client or server
- Readable code

What is allowed:

- still have 3 private methods : server, common and client

What i want to avoid:

- case (unless it is readable / short)
- if

Things i was thinking of:

- enums (to specify client and server) and a case (better then to use meaningless ints or booleans)
- annotations (@clientside) (@serverside)

### Edit:

My classes are loaded in by an api, an example client/server method would be init. so in my main class i need to run that method for all the classes that need initialization.

Comment: Did you consider a) Behavioral Design patterns? b) Composition in general? c) Inheritance?

Comment: It depends. I don't think you've provided enough information to answer this. An if statement might work, extract the behaviour to a client class might work in combination with a template method/composition/inheritance, but it might also be overkill. Like I said, it depends, and it depends on how much code you have, but having an annotation...that's weird magic you probably don't need. Also, an enum is hardly better than a boolean.

Comment: Most of these methods are only 5 lines long but i have a lot in a lot of classes. i want to avoid to have 2 completly different projects for client and server. hence i want to know a way to specifify which method to use. 
@Erik i wouldn't use a boolean since it doesn't relate to client or server. why should true be client for ex. (still prob the most efficient solution). i would still use an enum or static variables: method(enum.clientside) or method(myclass.clientside) . i want to know if there is a better other then giving a parameter to specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you (and if I understand your needs) I would use a common interface implemented by a client and a server class, with an abstract class in the middle:

```
public interface Example {
    public void method();
}

public abstract class AbstractExample implements Example {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        common();
        implMethod();
    }

    private void common() {
        // common implementation
    }

    protected abstract void implMethod();
}

public class ExampleClientImpl extends AbstractExample {

    @Override
    protected void implMethod() {
        // client implementation
    }
}

public class ExampleServerImpl extends AbstractExample {

    @Override
    protected void implMethod() {
        // server implementation
    }
}
```

With this approach you can also split your classes in common/client/server packages or better modules.